# Wordpress plugin delete and delete it's database tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have made a plugin that uses a database with tables created like this:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_install' );
function plugin_install() {
global $wpdb;
$table1 = $wpdb->prefix . 'table1';
            $charset_collate = '';
            if ( ! empty( $wpdb->charset ) ) {
                  $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$wpdb->charset}";
                }
            if ( ! empty( $wpdb->collate ) ) {
                  $charset_collate .= " COLLATE {$wpdb->collate}";
                }

                $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table1 (
                    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    some_data varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
                    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
                ) $charset_collate;";

            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
            dbDelta( $sql );
            }
```

I don't know how to delete all these tables when the plugin is deleted via the admin panel. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same on the other way: `register_uninstall_hook($file, $callback)`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook

For example:

```
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'plugin_uninstall');
function plugin_uninstall() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table1 = $wpdb->prefix . 'table1';
    $sql = "DROP TABLE " . $table1;
    dbDelta($sql);
}
```